# keyboard key icon preview

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, keypreview

i have edited a custom keyboard that is in the sdk. well i am pretty much done.

the only problem was i wanted not to show icon preview of some keys like

- space
- enter
- shift
- alt
- delete

now i got how to disable the icon preview of these keys, but space and delet keys are repeatable (long press makes countinous action) so if the repeatable property is true then the preview for those keys are still shown.

and i have to turn the repeatable property off which is very annoying for those two keys. because to delete a word of lenth 5 i have to press delete button 5 times..